# How do I show a ` org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset`?

Tags: apache-spark

I have this data set and I'd like to print out the values.

I tried to do a count on the object and it gave me `res96: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[(Boolean, Long)] = [value: boolean, count(1): bigint]`.

That's from this code

```
mydf
    .count
```

I tried to do a show and I got this error

```
<console>:83: error: value show is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.KeyValueGroupedDataset[Boolean,com.asana.data.services.parquetlogs.ParsedLog]
possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value show'?
           .show
            ^
```

How do I reveal this data set?

Here's the code to create my dataframe

```
val groupedDF = mydf.groupByKey(mydf => {
    val group = mydf.value
    group
    })
```

Comment: can you post full code ?

Comment: Yep, I posted the full code

Comment: Also can you post input and expected output sample data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably grouped your dataframe before, so currently it doesn't have `show` method, you have to apply some aggregation function to it first.

To get to the current data, maybe try adding some mapping to it, like: `mydf.mapGroups{case(k, iter) => (k, iter.map(x => x._2).toArray)}`. Then you'll be able to call `show()` on the result.

Comment: Great, I posted the full code. I'll try mydf.mapGroups{case(k, iter) => (k, iter.map(x => x._2).toArray)}.show

Comment: It gave me back this error <console>:84: error: value _2 is not a member of com.[myinstance].data.services.parquetlogs.ParsedLog

Comment: you can try changing it to mydf.mapGroups{case(k, iter) => (k, iter.toArray)}

Basically, you need anything to get usual dataframe from grouped one.